# XPath (1.0) Match consecutive elements until specific child or end

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

This is for XPath 1.0.

Here is an example of the mark up that I am matching against. The actual number of elements is **not** known ahead of time and thus varies, but following this sort of of pattern:

```
<div class="entry">
    <p><iframe /></p>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Test 3</p>
    <p><iframe /></p>
    <p>
        <a>Test 4</a>
        <br />
        <a>Test 5</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to to match every `<p>` that does ***not*** contain an `<iframe>`, up until the next `<p>` that ***does*** contain an `<iframe>` or until the end of the enclosing `<div>` element.

To make things slightly more complicated, for specific reasons I need to use each `<iframe>` as the base, a la `//div[@class='entry']//iframe`, so that each nodeset is based from

```
(//div[@class='entry']//iframe)[1]
(//div[@class='entry']//iframe)[2]
...
```

and thus, in this case, matching

```
<p>Text 1</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
<p>Test 3</p>
```

and

```
<p>
    <a>Test 4</a>
    <br />
    <a>Test 5</a>
</p>
```

respectively.

I tried some of the following for testing to no avail:

```
(//div[@class='entry']//iframe)/ancestor::p/following-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::p[iframe]]
```

(or for testing):

```
(//div[@class='entry']//iframe)[1]/ancestor::p/following-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::p[iframe]]
(//div[@class='entry']//iframe)[2]/ancestor::p/following-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::p[iframe]]
```

and some variations thereof but what happens for the first set is it gets all `<iframe>`-less `<p>` elements all the way to the end instead of stopping at the next `<p>` that contains a `<iframe>`.

I've been at this for a while and even though I'm usually quite handy with this sort of thing, I can't quite work my way thorigh this one and none of the search results from Google and such have helped.

Thanks. Any help is always appreciated.

Edit: It can be assumed that there is only one occurrence of `<div class="entry">` in the document.

Comment: I doubt this is possible in a single pure XPath 1.0 expression without access to functions like the XSLT `current()` and `generate-id()` - essentially you need some way of saying "p elements whose nearest preceding iframe is _the node you first thought of_". It is possible in two steps if you can calculate a value in one xpath and use that value as part of another - what tool or library are you using here?

Comment: ... or in XPath 2.0 with a `for $x in .. return` trick.

Comment: I see your latest edit but you haven't answered the most important question so I'll ask again - what tool or library are you using to execute your XPath expressions?  I'm pretty sure what you want can't be done in one single XPath 1.0 expression, so the answer will depend on the host language or environment.  If you're calling into XPath from your own code please edit the question to show an example of that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for can't be done in one single XPath 1.0 expression without help.  The problem is that the question you want to ask is

> Starting from an element X (the p-containing-an-iframe), find the other `p` elements for which that element's nearest preceding p-with-an-iframe is the original node X

If we had a variable `$x` holding a reference to the top-level context node (the `p[iframe]` we're starting from) then you could say something like the following (in XPath 2.0)

```
following-sibling::p[not(iframe)][preceding-sibling::p[iframe][1] is $x]
```

XPath 1.0 doesn't have an `is` operator to compare node identity but there are other proxies you can use for this, for example

```
following-sibling::p[not(iframe)][count(preceding-sibling::p[iframe])
                               = (count($x/preceding-sibling::p[iframe]) + 1)]
```

i.e. those following `p` elements that have one more `preceding-sibling::p[iframe]` than `$x` has.

The nub of the problem then is how to get at the outer context node from inside the inner predicate - pure XPath 1.0 has no way to do this.  In XSLT you have the `current()` function, but otherwise you have two basic choices:

- If your XPath library allows you to provide variable bindings to your expressions, then inject a variable `$x` containing the context node and use the expression I've given above.
- If you can't inject variables then use two separate XPath queries in sequence.

First execute the expression

```
count(preceding-sibling::p[iframe]) + 1
```

with the relevant `p[iframe]` as context node, and take the result as a number.  Or alternatively, if you're already iterating over these `p[iframe]` elements in your host language then just take the iteration number from there directly, you don't need to count it up using XPath.  Either way, you can then build a second expression dynamically:

```
following-sibling::p[not(iframe)][count(preceding-sibling::p[iframe]) = N]
```

(where `N` is the result of the first expression/iteration counter) and evaluate that with the same context node, taking the final result as a node set.

Comment: Thanks. Great informative answer. I suspected as much regarding XPath 1.0 and what you said about it needing assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood completely, but sometimes it helps to comment on an attempted solution rather than trying to explain.

Please try the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@class='entry']//iframe//p[not(descendant::iframe)]
```

And let me know if this yields the correct result.

If not,

- explain how the result differs from what you need
- please show a more complete HTML sample: a reasonable document with multiple `div` elements, and more than one where `div[@class = 'entry']` - and otherwise covering all the complexity you describe.
- explain why you added `[1]` and `[2]` to your expressions
- give more details about the platform you're using XPath with, perhaps post code

Comment: **1)** I'm not looking for `<p>` elements *within* `<iframe>` elements, but `<p>` elements that are siblings of the ones containing `<iframe>` (see example markup.) **2)** Please assume there is only one `<div class="entry">` **3)** I used the `[1]` and `[2]` to show each nodeset that would otherwise be obtained from looping.